# Would prefer and prefer

Tags: modal-verbs

When I say for instance: " I would prefer you to stay here" it refers to the presence and future. What about when I want tp refer to the past? I would prefer you stayed is fine or there is some other way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I would think ( that ) ... vs I think ...?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/211166/i-would-think-that-vs-i-think)

Comment: _I would have preferred you to stay_ (but you didn't).

Comment: If you're referring to the past, you just say *I would **have preferred** X* rather than *I would prefer X*. Note that it's fine in the present not to include ***would*** (it means nothing anyway - it's just a "politeness" indicator). But whereas *I **prefer** X* is "natural", *I **preferred** X* isn't very natural (and when it *does* occur, it usually implies a preferrence *that was satisfied*, whereas *I **would have** preferred X* strongly implies the speaker *didn't* get what they wanted.

Comment: This question needs more clarity to answer effectively.  It is unclear whether the past of the preferring is being referred to or the past of staying or both.  Also, two different constructions in the post are used with "prefer": "prefer someone to do something" and "prefer (that) someone do something.  These require different answers.  Lastly, "prefer" and "would prefer" also use tend to use different constructions.  If the poster gave a more complete hypothetical describing the situation they want to express, it would be easier to answer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers There is a difference between 'prefer' and 'would prefer'. 'prefer' is used to say what you prefer in general and 'would prefer' is used to say what somebody wants in a specific situation

Comment: @kyadere: I don't really recognize that distinction as such. But the *effect* of being in a "specific situation" is usually that you're politely requesting the addressee to indulge your preference. And the times when you're announcing your "general preference" will often be those where you're *not* under any obligation to be polite (often, specifically contexts where you're being "assertive"). And suppose you were asked whether you wanted tea or coffee: *"Well, I **would prefer** [general case] cocoa, but I guess I prefer [this case] tea".*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, I just wanted to mention the distinction I came across. It is given, for example, by English Grammar in Use. That's all.

Comment: @kyadere: I suppose the observation is often true, even if I don't recognize it *as an inherent distinction*. But it's not *really* helpful for learners to devote brain cells to remembering it, since it should arise naturally through the "polite deference" implication that they *need* to commit to memory (because other things *flow* from it). But sometime "interesting" facts help keep you alert and help you remember other things! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers If you trust English Grammar in Use then learning this rule is useful because it relates directly to meaning. It doesn't matter if you want to be polite or not. 'Generally, I would rather drive rather than travel by train' is incorrect because of the way 'would rather' is used. "We use would prefer to say what somebody wants in a specific situation (not in general)". But I'm guessing that you prefer to trust yourself more than sources so I won't continue this thread.

Comment: I won't continue the thread either, except to point out that if "trusting sources" has led you to think *'Generally, I would rather drive rather than travel by train' is incorrect because of the way 'would rather' is used* then you've been *seriously* miseducated!

Answer (score 2):

You can use perfect infinitives:

- I would prefer you to have stayed
- I would have preferred you to stay
- I would have preferred you to have stayed

Comment: I would prefer you stay or stayed.

Comment: I would have preferred for you to have stayed. I would have preferred that you should have stayed. There are always more ways to skin this particular cat!